# Как оптимизировать css?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите какие-нибудь инструменты для чистки css. Чтобы всё, к чему не обращается html удалить. Т.е. нужно из css выкинуть всё лишнее, чтобы страница при этом не пострадала. Довольно часто нужно, приходится много времени убивать, чтобы сделать это вручную, хотя наверняка уже давно придумали как это автоматизировать.

Comment: на пример gulp uncss

Comment: да, типа этого, спасибо. Только желательно в виде приложения для Windows, т.к. ставить только для этих целей gulp не очень бы хотелось.

Answer (score 0):

В Google Chrome есть инструмент.

<kbd>F12</kbd> -> вкладка «Audits» -> кнопка «RUN» -> пункт «Remove unused CSS rules».

Comment: Есть да, я это видел, оно находит всё неиспользуемое, но как удалить то?